# SharePoint 2013 import data from Access

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, microsoft-access

I am trying to build a DR application to a SharePoint site using Access 2013. This Access DB will be available when the SP site goes down. and once the SP site is up, all items created in Access DB has to be moved to SP list. Any idea on how to get started with this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy to do.

You can link access to the sharepoint list, go to external data, click the more arrow and Sharepoint list will be at the top.   Just navigate to the site collection and list which you have your list.  In Access 2013 it always links to the default view of Your sharepoint list.

Once the list is linked it behaves like a linked table so you can query it, update etc.

Now just write a query that appends your offline data to sharpoint - as long as your filling in all the fields that you have set as mandatory on the sharepoint list access will creat new records in sharpoint.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried creating this way and linked SP list and Access table. But looks like the Multiple line of text fields are set to Read only in Access table.

Comment: Yes your right it's a memo field in access - suspect your field in sharepoint isn't rich text format?   Try changing it in sharepoint and try it again